# Why entering animation is not working in new thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-animation

Entry Transition animation not working when starting activity from new thread.

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent listIntent = new Intent(HomeFragment.this.getActivity(),
                            ListActivity.class);
                    listIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.type_id), data.get(i).getType_id());
                    listIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.translation_title), data.get(i).getTranslate_type());
                    startActivity(listIntent);
                    getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.fade_in);
                }
            }).start();
```

But transition animation works in ui thread. Why entering animation is not working in new thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply use this:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
         Intent listIntent = new Intent(HomeFragment.this.getActivity(),
                        ListActivity.class);
         listIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.type_id), data.get(i).getType_id());
         listIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.translation_title), data.get(i).getTranslate_type());
         startActivity(listIntent);
         getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.fade_in);
    }
}, 100);
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: Thank you buddy. It's working :) Can you tell me why is it behaving weirdly?

Comment: "new Thread" on your call is considered as creating a new thread which is not main thread (which can't starting a new activity)

As fixed in this answer, using handler will run in the thread you call it (probably UI thread)

Answer (score 1):

Your call on launching a new activity is consider as a UI part, please do it in UI thread only,

as launching new activity will occupied your whole screen, pausing old animation before may be a better solution as your animation is not seen by user anyway

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Why create a separate thread for creating an activity?

```
Intent intent = new Intent( getContext(), ListActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: My UI thread is doing animation. When creating an activity in UI thread, animation janks! that's why I am going for a new thread.